# Homomorphisms on Direct Products of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have seen this question on this site so I know this is a duplicate. I do not understand all the explanations on the other questions and they are years old.

> Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. Suppose $J$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$. Show that $f(x,y)=(Jx,Ky)$ is a homomorphism from $G\times H$ onto $(G/J)\times (H/K)$.

I believe I would begin with supposing $(x,y),(a,b) \in G$ then $f(x,y)f(a,b)=(Jx,Ky)(Ja, Kb)$. I'm a little rusty on my multiplicative skills but I believe that $(Jx,Ky)(Ja,Kb)=(JxJa,KyKb)$. This would be $f((x,y)(a,b))$ thus $G\times H$ is a homomorphism.

As for the kernal, it would be some $\{(x,y)\in G : (x,y)=(0,0)\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that $(Jx,Ky)(Ja,Kb)=(JxJa,\,KyKb)$

-- well, this is coming from the definition of the group operation on the direct product (namely $(x,y)(a,b):=(xa,yb)$).

> As for the kernal, it would be some $\{(x,y)\in G:(x,y)=(0,0)\}$

-- You might have just learnt vector spaces or modules recently. 
For a general group, the group operation is not assumed to be commutative and thus we rather use the multiplicative terminology, and the neutral element is denoted by $1$ (or $e$). So, the kernel is
$$\ker f=\big\{(x,y)\in G:f(x,y)=(1_{G/J},\ 1_{H/K})\big\} $$
where $1_{G/J}$ is the identity element in the quotient group $G/J$, i.e. its the coset $J$ itself in the coset terminology. 
So, $(x,y)\in\ker f\ $ iff $\ Jx=J$ and $Ky=K\ $ iff $\ x\in J$ and $y\in K\ $ iff $\ (x,y)\in J\times K$.

Answer (score 1):

suppose $(x,y), (a,b)\in G\times H$

f is a homeomorphism if:

$f(xa,yb) = f(x,y)f(a,b)$

$f(xa,yb) = (Jxa, Kyb)\\
f(x,y)f(a,b) = (JxJa, KyKb)$

$Jx$ is the coset, created when every $j\in J$ multiplies by $x$

$J,K$ is normal $\implies$ the left cosets equal the right cosets.

i.e. $xJ = Jx$

$f(x,y)f(a,b) = (JJxa, KKyb)$

And since J, K are subgroups the product of any two elements in the subgroup returns another element in the subgroup.

$f(x,y)f(a,b) = (Jxa, Kyb) = f(xa,yb)$

The kernel would be $J\times K$